# Ansible Jinja2 string comparison

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am getting value of variable "env" in Jinja2 template file using a variable defined in group_vars like:

```
env: "{{ defined_variable.split('-')[0] }}"
```

`env` possible three values could be `abc`, `def`, `xyz`.

On the basis of this value I want to use server URL, whose possible values I have defined inside `defaults/main.yml` as:

```
server_abc: https://xxxx.xxx.com
server_def: https://xxxxx.xxx.com
server_xyz: https://xxxx.xxx.com
```

In Jinja2 template, I am trying to do:

```
{% if 'abc'  == "{{env}}" %}
serverURL: '{{ server_abc }}'
{% elif 'def'  == "{{env}}" %}
serverURL: '{{ server_def}}'
{% elif 'xyz' == "{{env}}" %}
 serverURL: '{{ server_xyz }}'
{% else %}
ServerURL: 'server Url not found'
{% endif %}
```

However it is always ending up defining `ServerURL = "server URL not found"` even if `env` comes with value of `abc`, `def` or `xyz`.

If I try to replace env in Jinja2 template (hardcoded) like below condition does satisfy to true:

```
     {% if 'abc'  == "abc" %}
     serverURL: '{{ server_abc }}'
```

So that implies me syntax is true but the value of `"{{env}}"` at run time is not evaluated.

Any suggestion what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You don't need quotes and braces to refer to variables inside expressions. The correct syntax is:

```
{% if 'abc' == env %}
serverURL: '{{ server_abc }}'
{% elif 'def' == env %}
serverURL: '{{ server_def }}'
{% elif 'xyz' == env %}
serverURL: '{{ server_xyz }}'
{% else %}
ServerURL: 'server URL not found'
{% endif %}
```

Otherwise you compare two strings, for example `abc` and `{{env}}` and you always get a negative result.

Comment: Even after removing braces from the env, it is ending on server URL not found

Comment: if I use any other variable from group vars, the expression does evaluate to be true in match condition, however the env variable is getting populated in same jinja teamplate file by expression:-
env: "{{ defined_variable.split('-')[0] }}"

Comment: I was able to achieve purpose by having my conditional statement as
if 
% if 'abc' == defined_variable.split('-')[0] %}
serverURL: '{{ server_abc }}'